# Web3 read contract Python

Tags: python-3.x, blockchain, web3py, etherscan

Could you tell me please, how i can call function in contract https://bscscan.com/address/0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F#readContract?

I use python

```
def str_to_addr(s: str):
    if s.startswith("0x"):
        return Address(bytes.fromhex(s[2:]))
    elif s.endswith(".eth"):
        return ENS(s)

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/....'))
router_address = str_to_addr("0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F")
router = w3.eth.contract(address=router_address, abi=abi)
print(router.functions.factory().call())
```

But i get error web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?

What i should do?